# pygame - return key pressed before event.key handler results in immediate processing of event.key block

Tags: python, pygame

In my program made with pygame, I have an intro sequence that blits a total of 3 text boxes to the screen timed apart from each other, so one appears, then the next, then the one after that. I have no event polling during this time, as I want the whole sequence to play for it's total of probably around 10 seconds. However, after this sequence plays, I have a 'Continue' text that appears in the bottom right to show the user to press Return to continue to the next slide. This is where I then have my event handler like so:

```
exited = False
    while not exited:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exited = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    exited = True
```

However, if the user hits Return at any time in this sequence, once the control flow hits the event handler, it just exits immediately through the pygame.KEYDOWN branch. How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by actually just adding

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    pass
```

before my next pygame.event.get() loop. The first one consumes the other events that happened in the sequence, so that the second loop will only handle input given after the sequence plays.